# How can I write this power series as a power series representation?

Tags: probability, power-series, generating-functions

How can I write this power series ($1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5+4x^6+4x^7+5x^8....$) as a power series representation (like $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ or something neat like that)?

Comment: This is S(1+x) where $S=1+2x^2+3x^4+...$ for a start.

Comment: @paul: What about x?

Comment: @Paul Saying $(1+x)S(x)$ might be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** using $y=x^2$ and derivative in $y$: $$(1+x)(1+2x^2+3x^4+\ldots) $$
$$ =(1+x)(1+2y+3y^2+4y^3 +\ldots)$$
$$= (1+x)(y+y^2+y^3+y^4+\ldots)'$$
$$ = (1+x)\left( \frac{y}{1-y}\right)'$$

**Edit:**
$$ = (1+x) \frac{1}{(1-y)^2} $$
$$ = \frac{1+x}{(1-x^2)^2}  $$
$$ = \frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}.$$

Comment: I believe $(y+y^2+y^3+y^4+....)$ = $\frac{1}{1-y}$, if I am not mistaken. Then is it: $\frac{1+x}{1-y}$?

Comment: Oh wait, I see that you had $\frac{y}{1-y}$ instead. Is it: $\frac{(1+x)(y)}{1-y}$?

Comment: And $\frac{(1+x)(y)}{1-y}$, and $y=x^2$, then $\frac{(1+x)(x^2)}{1-x^2}$?

Comment: Simplifying would result in: $\frac{x^2}{1-x}$?

Comment: Just take derivative in y of $y/(1-y)$, then replace $y$ with $x^2$.

Comment: yep, i did. i got $\frac{x^2}{1-x}$, but I see that SBareS had $\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ instead. Which one is correct?

Comment: you should get $(1+x)/(1-x^2)^2$

Comment: confirmation is here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=infinite+series+%281%2Bx%29%2F%281-x%5E2%29%5E2

Comment: Can I ask you a further question? I will move the discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19624/discussion-between-mathy-person-and-ir7).

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this by first splitting the series up:

$$1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5+...=(1+x)(1+2x^2+3x^4+...)$$

Letting $s=1+2x^2+3x^4$ we can do a few tricks:

$$s-x^2s=\begin{array}{c} 1&+2x^2&+3x^4+... \\ &-x^2&-2x^4-...\end{array}$$
$$=1+x^2+x^4+...$$

Which converges to $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ for $-1 < x < 1$ (proving this is not hard, and can be done by a technique like the above). This gives

$$s -x^2s=\frac{1}{1-x^2}\Leftrightarrow s=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}=$$

Thus the original series converges to:

$$(1+x)s=\frac{(1+x)}{(1-x^2)^2}$$

For $-1 < x - 1$.

Comment: Hmm..I got $\frac{x^2}{1-x}$ (see what I posted in reply to ir7's comment). Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Whoops my bad, I forgot a step

Comment: Apparently I am to tired for maths right now...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, it is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{2n-2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{2n-1}$$
If you can compute one of the two terms, e.g. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{2n-2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^{2n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(x^{2})^n$ (see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn?lq=1), then you'll also get the other term (by multiplying it by $x$), and thus the sum.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to look at 
$$
1+2x^2+3x^4+4x^6+5x^8+\dots
$$
as
$$
1+2t+3t^2+4t^3+5t^4+\dots
$$
where $t=x^2$. The last series is the derivative of
$$
1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4+t^5+\dots=\frac1{1-t}
$$
Therefore,
$$
1+2t+3t^2+4t^3+5t^4+\dots=\frac1{(1-t)^2}
$$
and
$$
1+2x^2+3x^4+4x^6+5x^8+\dots=\frac1{(1-x^2)^2}
$$
Now, just multiply by $1+x$:
$$
\begin{align}
1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5+4x^6+4x^7+5x^8+5x^9+\dots
&=\frac{1+x}{(1-x^2)^2}\\
&=\frac1{(1-x)(1-x^2)}
\end{align}
$$